# apache redirect http to https without www

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Trying to redirect all `http` and none-`www` traffic to `https` (with or without www).
Using `.htaccess` and `apache VirtualHost` files:

**VirtualHost file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName adi-md.co.il
    ServerAlias www.adi-md.co.il
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^adi-md.co.il
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.adi-md.co.il
```

**option 1**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^adi-md.co.il
```

**option 2**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

When typing just `adi-md.co.il` you get the the server's default page.

How do I fix it so all traffic is both redirected to `https` as well as the none-`www` requests??

**Note:**
I have looked at these 3 but they do not supply an answer (2 out 3 deal with www to none-www)

[apache redirect http to https and www to non www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945655/apache-redirect-http-to-https-and-www-to-non-www)
[http to https apache redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection)
[Redirect from http to https without www using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28814170/redirect-from-http-to-https-without-www-using-htaccess)

Comment: Checkout http://redirect-www.org/

Answer (score 1):

Two simple rules for redirect http to https without www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is it possible to use these rules. But ignore them when .local domain host is used?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

This basically first checks if if you either have `www` enabled and `HTTPs` turned on. If either are, it will switch it back to `HTTP` and remove `www`.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: somehow this didn't do the job...I updated my question's `.htaccess` file